# $PYENV_ROOT/bin doesn't exist after installing pyenv

Tags: macos, pyenv

The instructions for installing pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv say to add `$PYENV_ROOT/bin` to path. On my M1 Mac running OSX 13, that directory does not exist. Checking pyenv's gitter, many others have also noticed this problem (but there is no response there). Furthermore, the binaries should be under the shims directory. Does the fact that `$PYENV_ROOT/bin` doesn't exist mean I have installed pyenv incorrectly? Or is this a vestigial step in the installation?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I installed pyenv via brew but the pyenv binaries ended up in /opt/homebrew/bin/pyenv

Initialising pyenv was an issue for me as I didn't have the right order of commands in my ~/.bash_profile, it needed to be in this order

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```